# Convert string with time data to rtc_time structure in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, real-time-clock

I can easily convert kernel data type `struct rtc_time` to string with help `sprintf()`,
but I can't do reverse operation:

```
 string "Thu Aug 23 14:55:02 2001" to rtc_time structure
```

Should I write my own realisation if `strptime()` function into my kernel module?

Could anyone prompt me?

Comment: Yes, for printing we have `%ptR` extension, but for parsing there is nothing in kernel. Why do you need one?

Comment: @0andriy , I write a driver for a rtc i2c chip and I have exported some attributes to sysfs for ability to enable/disable alarm interrupts. 
To set interrupt time i should do:
```echo "Thu Aug 23 00:03:02 2020"  >> /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/alarm_time" ```
After this my attribute method `store` will be called, and I must convert this string to rtc_time structure

Comment: Why would you have an interface that allows inconsistent input (i.e. a day-of-week and date)?  Why not use an all-numeric format such the **date** shell command?

Comment: @sawdust, i use `hwclock` and the one gives me time as:
```Fri Feb 14 01:25:41 2020  0.000000 seconds```

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed.  Why would you use the output of `hwclock` (i.e. the *current* time) to set an alarm time (e.g. a *future* time)?

Comment: @sawdust, No, i don't use hwclock output to set alarm. Maybe I confused you, excuse me:)
I use hwclock like an user space utility with help which I can read/write usual time to/from my rtc chip. hwclock gives time in this format ```Fri Feb 14 01:25:41 2020```.  I use sysfs attributes to set alarm time.

Comment: I just wanted to do input forman for sysfs like the output format of hwclock.
F.e ```echo "Thu Aug 23 00:03:02 2020" >> /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/alarm_time"```
But i can use anyone data format for my own attribute

Comment: RTC subsystem has its own ABI, don't do custom one, except the case if you are just learning to program in kernel. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/rtc.html

Comment: Thank you for this link. I will learn it.
Yes, you have guessed, i am a new in kernel/driver programming